# Cannot "project gostats" in multi-project build with ProjectRef in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I've the following `Build` project definition that sets up a multi-project build:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object Build extends Build {
  lazy val gostats = ProjectRef(id = "gostats", base = file("modules/gostats_0.1"))

  lazy val godeploy = Project(id = "godeploy", base = file("."))
    .aggregate(gostats).dependsOn(gostats)
}
```

This compiles fine, but I cannot run `project gostats` in the SBT console.

If I change `ProjectRef` to `Project` for `gostats`, `gostats` no longer compiles because SBT ignores my project settings in this case.

How can I get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you work with SBT `0.13.x` you can define [Multi-Project Builds](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html) in `build.sbt`. Here's one that defines `godeploy` and `gostats` following the object `Build` of yours.

```
lazy val godeploy = project in file(".") aggregate gostats dependsOn gostats

lazy val gostats = project in file("modules") / "gostats_0.1"
```

With this, I can `project` the projects with no errors.

```
[godeploy]> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1-project-ref/
[info]   * godeploy
[info]     gostats
[godeploy]> project gostats
[info] Set current project to gostats (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1-project-ref/)
[gostats]> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1-project-ref/
[info]     godeploy
[info]   * gostats
[gostats]> compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1-project-ref/}gostats...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 11, 2014 2:23:34 PM
```

SBT has also created the project directory structure for me as I only started with `build.sbt` and `project/build.properties` files.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1-project-ref
$ tree -L 2
.
├── build.sbt
├── modules
│   └── gostats_0.1
└── project
    └── build.properties

3 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was very helpful.

I didn't think to switch to using `build.sbt`.  Now my dependencies work fine and I can switch projects.